# Does bc support hex calculations?

Tags: bc, calculator

I'm trying to do a `hex` calculation directly with `bc`, I already specified the scale.

```
echo 'scale=16;c06b1000-c06a5e78' | bc
```

But I still get a zero. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
echo 'ibase=16;C06D1000-C06A5E78' | bc
176520
```

Note that only UPPER CASE hex digits are supported as lower case ones would conflict with function and variable names, which is why you got 0 in your example (`var1 - var2`)

If you need the answer in hex too, just set the `obase` variable:

```
echo 'obase=16;ibase=16;C06D1000-C06A5E78' | bc
2B188
```

PS: FYI `scale` isn't designed for conversion base. From `man bc`:

```
scale defines how some operations use digits after the decimal point.
The default value of scale is 0.
```

Comment: So the real answer on 'what could be wrong' is that bc only supports UPPER CASE for the hex digits, with credits to editor Stephane.

Comment: Note that it's important to set `obase` before you set `ibase`. If you set `ibase` first, then it affects the value parsed for `obase` too. ie `ibase = 16; obase = 16;` sets `obase` to 0x16 = 22